# How to display DialogBox on blur event and prevent onBlur re-firing while interacting with the DialogBox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

React, Material UI:

As shown in the code below, I have a table with a column of TextFields. On blur/focusOut event, the TextFields call the validateItem() method that makes a server request to validate the item. If validation fails, the UI should throw up a DialogBox with the Error message. After user clicks 'OK' on the DialogBox **(or clicks anywhere else on the screen to close the DialogBox, or does any other action)**, the DialogBox should close and that same TextField should be cleared and focused on so the user can re-enter valid data.

However, when user clicks Ok in the DialogBox (or does any other action when the Box is displayed), the OnBlur and validateItem() gets triggered again, and so the DialogBox is re-opened. How to prevent this behavior, and refocus on the same Textfield as mentioned?

I was thinking maybe after the DialogBox is opened, the UI could somehow wait for the user's input until the box is closed (to prevent onBlur triggering on any action), but idk how to achieve that.

```
export const MyComponent = ({initialPrompts}: any) => {

  const [prompts, setPrompts] = useState<ServerData[]>(initialPrompts);
  const [errorDialogOpen, setErrorDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [errorErrorMsg, setErrorErrorMsg] = useState('');

  const handleDialogOpen = () => {
    setErrorDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setErrorDialogOpen(false);
  };

  async function validateItem(e: any, promptId: number, arrIndex: number) {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5276/Validateitems?promptId=${promptId}&item=${e.target.value}`);
    
    if (!response.ok) {
      const text = await response.text();
      setErrorErrorMsg(text)
      handleDialogOpen();
      throw new Error("An item validation error has occurred.");
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    // TODO: make sure data is sucesss
    if (response.ok) {
      const updatedPrompts = prompts.map(x => x.promptId === promptId ? { ...x, isValidateditem: true} : x );
      setPrompts(updatedPrompts);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ width: '700px' }}>
      <Dialog open={errorDialogOpen} onClose={handleDialogClose} >
        <DialogTitle> {"Error"} </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText> {errorErrorMsg} </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleDialogClose} autoFocus> OK </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table size="small">
          <TableBody>{
            prompts.map((item, index) => <TableRow key={'trow'+index}>
              <TableCell>{item.prompt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <TextField key={'tfield'+index}
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                  fullWidth
                  error={item.isValidateditem === false}
                  inputRef={(input) => index === 0 && input?.focus()}
                  onBlur={(e) => validateItem(e, item.promptId, index)}
                />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>)
          }</TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <br/>
      <Button variant="contained" size='small'>Done</Button>
      <Button variant="contained" size='small' style={{float: 'right'}}>Reset</Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have one idea how to work around this error.

Try setting another state for example `preventBlur` that is initially false. Every time `DialogBox` is opened set it to true. Inside `validateItem` function check value of `preventBlur` if it is true return from the function and try setting it to false.

> I hope that this will help.